# What is wrong with calculating the probability this way?

Tags: probability, combinatorics

A footbal team is playing a tournament of five matches. The probabilities that they win, draw or lose a match are $\frac{1}{2}, \frac{1}{6}$ and $\frac{1}{3}$ respectively. The result of a match is independent of the results of other matches. At the end of the tournament the coach gets fired if they lose three consecutive matches. Find the probability that the coach loses his job.

My approach:

The probability that the team loses 3 matches in a row is $(\frac{1}{3})^3$. If they are to lose three consecutive matches out of five then they can lose the matches 1, 2, 3 or 2, 3, 4 or 3, 4, 5. So the probability is $P=(\frac{1}{3})^3*3=\frac{1}{9}$. I didn't consider if the team loses 4 or 5 consecutive matches because 3 is enough to get the coach fired. So whether the remaining two matches in each of the situation are won, lost or end up in draw doesn't matter.

However, it looks like it does matter or there is something else wrong with my approach.

My questions:

1) What is wrong with my method?

2) How should I solve it correctly?

EDIT: The questions asks for three **or more** loses.
The answer is $\frac{7}{81}$.

Comment: you have to take into account the outcomes of the other two matches which must not be lost...

Comment: How many ways can you form three consecutive losses out of 5 matches?

Comment: It does matter: for instance, you've counted the case in which the team loses all $5$ matches $3$ times, once in each of your three categories. (Also, $\left(\frac{1}3\right)^3\cdot 3=\frac{1}9$, not $\frac{10}{27}$.)

Comment: A straightforward approach is to calculate the probability of $5$ losses, the probability of exactly $4$ losses in a row, and the probability of exactly $3$ losses in a row and add them. Only the last of these is a little tricky: you have to distinguish the case in which the three losses in a row are the second, third, and fourth matches from the case in which they're the first $3$ or the last $3$ matches. In the latter case there can be a fourth loss; it just can't be adjacent to the other $3$.

Comment: According to your method: if there is a tournament of 1000 matches, and the coach loses his job if they lose 3 consecutive matches, then the probability that the coach loses his job is 998/81, a probability of more than 1.  Can you see what is wrong now?

Answer (score 1):

The coach gets fired in the following cases:

- They lose exactly 3 games, all consecutive:
  the probability of one string with exactly three lost games is
  $\left(\frac{1}{3}\right)^3*\left(\frac{2}{3}\right)^2$, and there are 3 such configurations with consecutive lost games.
- They lose exactly 4 games, with at least three consecutive:
  the probability of one string with exactly four lost games is
  $\left(\frac{1}{3}\right)^4*\frac{2}{3}$, and there are 4 such configurations with consecutive lost games (the non-lost game can be any but the third one).
- They lose all 5 games: with probability $\left(\frac{1}{3}\right)^5$.

So the probability of losing at least three consecutive games is

$$\left(\frac{1}{3}\right)^3*\left(\frac{2}{3}\right)^2*3+ \left(\frac{1}{3}\right)^4*\frac{2}{3}*4+ \left(\frac{1}{3}\right)^5= \frac{12+8+1}{3^5}=\frac{7}{3^4}=\frac{7}{81}$$

Your calculation $3*(1/3)^3=1/9>7/81$ is wrong because it overcounts configurations of the second and third type.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean 'exactly 3'? Then you have just 3$\times 2^2$ number of outcomes. You must account for the 4 remaining outcomes: ww, wd, dw, dd.

Comment: Three or more..

Comment: Then you need to account for 2 more cases: $llllx, xllll$ where x is either win or draw

Answer (score 0):

With $\bullet$ representing wins or draws, and $\circ$ representing **any** result,
sequences by which the coach gets fired are:

$LLL\circ \circ\;\;\bullet  LLL\circ\;\;\circ\bullet LLL\;\;$

We needn't worry about $\circ's, \;Pr = (1/3)^3(1 + 2/3 + 2/3 )$

Multiply and add up to get $Pr = \dfrac{7}{81}$